# SQL question: If Artikel has mutliple art types but one of the types is 'RS' then display Artikel as '1'

Tags: sql

I understand how to display it in a case when type as boolean but to allow me to display the artikel as '1' if the artikel has multiple positions is where i am a little stumped at the moment.
eg.

```
SELECT RESERVED = (SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT TOP 1 ART FROM ARTIKEL WHERE 
LAGER.ARTIKEL = ARTIKEL.ARTIEKL) = 'RS' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END)
FROM LAGER
```

problem is multiple arts/positions so of course it takes the first but when artikel has mutliple arts/positions it should still display as '1'

> error when top 1 is removed because it has multiple values

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: ssms is the database but i'll have to redesign it anyway because it is used in the front end application with a weird style in c#

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` or `EXISTS` if you want to check if one match exists:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM ARTIKEL A
                          WHERE A.ARTIKEL = L.ARTIEKL AND
                                A.ART = 'RS'
                         )
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS RESERVED 
FROM LAGER L;
```

Use `COUNT()` if you want to check for multiple values as well as one being `'RS'`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM ARTIKEL A
                          WHERE A.ARTIKEL = L.ARTIEKL AND
                                A.ART = 'RS'
                         ) AND
                   (SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM ARTIKEL A
                    WHERE A.ARTIKEL = L.ARTIEKL
                   ) > 1
             THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS RESERVED 
FROM LAGER L
```

Comment: thank you very much good people of the world, that was exactly what i was looking for, the other possibility is to build a udf but i need to learn more of it before i venture down that path

Answer (score 0):

Based on your query you can try this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT art FROM ARTIKEL WHERE ARTIKEL.ARTIKEL = LAGER.ARTIEKL AND ARTIKEL.ART = 'RS')
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS RESERVED 
FROM LAGER ;
```

Comment: didn't know you could use exist, i'll have to give a go